# routed network, subnetwork clients has broken tcp connection

Tags: tcp, route

I manage a linux server which works also as a router, and route between following networks:

- PPPoE (to connect to ISP) (default gw)
- wired network
- 2x VPN networks (PPTP and openVPN)
- wireless AP (DHCP)

All host is reachable from the linux server,the WAN, Wifi, VPN and LAN clients.
But somtimes from the LAN and AP, i can't access some webpages, here is a example:
Now the 8tracks.com is unreacheable (23.23.196.130).

first i try to reach from the AP (same result if i try from LAN)
connection established request sent but no answer come.

closed the connection after 7 secounds.

then i connected from the server, and page loaded successfully.

the other weird: if i try to connect through VPN, connection will be successfull.

i have same routing setting for all networks, firewall rules are unified for all interface.

I have no idea why works connection otherwise with other interface with same configuration.

[image: Netdump from a AP client and from the server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probably a legion of masquaraded/NAT-ted connections, too. Linux handles them in a static hash table, which can overflow. After that, you will get exactly this mystic problem.

A command

```
cat /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
```

says you, what is the upper limit of this hash map. Multiple this with 13 and set it with the command

```
echo #muchbiggernumber# >/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_max
```

If it was the cause of your problem, you can make this change permanent editing /etc/sysctl.conf intuitively.

Comment: And yes, that was the problem! Thanks, by your post, today i meet a new piece of important linux configuration. :)